# URI Schema: Infinite command prompts are opening

Tags: java, windows

I went through the following doc center and tried to create my own URI schema `myDocs`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Following is my Java program. It takes a command line argument and returns the URL in the browser.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;

public class URIOpen {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        String uri = args[0];

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(uri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I updated the (Default) value field of the command key like below.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" -cp "C:\Users\Krishna\Documents\Study\Miscellaneous\examples"  "URIOpen" "%1"
```

When I try to run the command `myDocs:http://google.com`, I end up opening infinite command prompts.

The following is my URI schema entry structure in the registry. Any help on this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution end up opening infinite command prompts because of:

1. you registered the execution of the custom `URIOpen` class to be activated by the system when it has to deal with `myDocs:`'s scheme based URI;
2. when custom `URIOpen` class executes the line `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(uri));` the system will receive again an URI based on the same scheme ( `myDocs:` ) and it will activate again a new command to execute your class again and again and again ...

Probably you **would like to change your code** in someway like that:

```java
    try {
        java.net.URI theURI = java.net.URI.create(uri);
        // System.out.println(theURI.getScheme()); => myDocs
        String uriBrowsablePart = theURI.getRawSchemeSpecificPart();
        // System.out.println(uriBrowsablePart); => http://google.com
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(uriBrowsablePart));
        // the above statement will open default browser on http://google.com
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

try replacing your try-catch block with my suggestion and see if it works as required.